# Inline translation tool is not working and i can't enable it

Tags: frontend, localisation, inline

Can't use inline translation tool in front end of my webpage. Its working fine in backend. 
I checked on the frontend if System>Config>Advanced>Developer>Translate Inline>"Enabled for Frontend" is enabled, but it wasn't. 
Soo... something is just not working here.

I'm asking you to help me out.

Comment: What exactly the method you're following to enable inline translation?

Comment: I just can't enable inline translation in frontend of my project. Admin panel shows its enabled, but when i get config to frontend it shows disabled

Comment: Are you using a custom template? Did you try if it works on the default Magento template?

Comment: If you have cache enabled on your site then try to clear it and check again. Sometimes due to cache changes wont reflect on front end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the config scope from the top-left select to store view. Maybe you have it enabled in global scope but it's still disabled in website scope or store view scope.

Comment: Thank you so much. It did the trick. So much headache for nothing.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure, that you have nothing entered in

```
System > Configuration > developer > Developer Restriction > Allowed IPs
```

or if you have, that your ip is part of it.

Comment: I already upvoted. :D

Comment: sometimes people makes funny mistakes like me to add ip and then worrying for gods sake why its not working. Thanks Fabian, your suggestion made it fixed.